# How to get path to the installed GIT in Python?

Tags: python, subprocess, osx-snow-leopard

I need to get a path to the GIT on Max OS X 10.6 using Python 2.6.1 into script variables. I use this code for that:

```
r = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("which git"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print r.stdout.read()
```

but the problem is that output is empty (I tried `stderr` too). It works fine with another commands such as `pwd` or `ls`.

Can anyone help me with that?

UPDATE: When I run `which git` from Terminal it prints out path as expected. So, `which` can find it.

UPDATE 2: I just created the bash script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
GP=`/usr/bin/which git`
PWD=`pwd`
echo "PATH IS: ${GP}"
echo "PWD IS: ${PWD}"
```

and output is

```
PATH IS: 
PWD IS: /Users/user/tmp
```

Comment: What you have works fine for me (though I'm not on OS X).  Could the two newlines (one from *which*, one from print) be causing you problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All which does is iterate over the directories in $PATH, checking to see if the file is there. Just write a small method to do likewise.

Comment: *which* also checks if the file is executable by the current user.

Comment: yep, problem was related to $PATH which was different (why?) from TextMate and our app.